# Inverted pendelum matrix derivative approximation

Tags: matlab, math, differential-equations

Here I've written a dynamic function as:

```
function dAx = dynamic(t,x)
global u;

g = 9.8;
l = 0.5;
m = 0.5;
h = 2;

dx(1,1) = x(2);
dx(2,1) = g/l*sin(x(1))-h/(m*l^2)*x(2)+1/(m*l)*cos(x(1))*u(1,1);
dx(3,1) = g*lcos(x(3))-u(2,1);


A = [x(1)*x(2)+10*x(1);10*x(2)-5*x(1);x(3)] 

dx = 1e-3
dAx = [(((x(1)+dx)+(x(1)-dx))*((x(2)+dx)+(x(2)-dx)))/(2*dx)+(10*(x(1)+dx)+(x(1)-dx))/(2*dx);
       ((10*(x(2)+dx)+(x(2)-dx))-5*((x(1)+dx)+(x(1)-dx)))/(2*dx);
       ((x(3)+dx)+(x(3)-dx))/(2*dx)]; % dA/dx using central derivative method computation
```

Here there is a matrix `A (3*1)` and function out put is `derivative of matrix A` related to system states.

I've tried to use **central difference method**.Is my derivative matrix calculation correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is math related question.

Comment: @lahidj You want us to proofread your MATLAB code, or your math?

Comment: Actually both of them if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

@Lahidj `dAx/dx` is a matrix of the size of `nA` by `nx`. You compute this column by column. Take the first state (eg. `x(1)`). Increment and decrement it by a small value `(dx)`, like 1e-3. Get the A vectors for increased and decreased values of alpha. Compute the difference between these two vectors and divide it by two times of `dx`. `(A_plus - A_minus)/(2*dx)`. Repeat this for the rest of the states/columns, you would get `dAx/dx`.

Comment: Yes,I've done this but there is something vague to me.The last part :"Repeat this for the rest of the states/columns, you would get dAx/dx." How? Also how can I get the  increased and decreased values of (x(1)) or ... .?